# Why did Verratti get a card for this back pass?

Tags: rules, football, officiating

During the match between PSG and Nantes, Marco Verratti was cautioned (received a yellow card) for [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccgpQBObhdc) pass to the goalkeeper, which was headed back rather than kicked.

I believe the referee has interpreted the behavior as unsportsmanlike, but do the rules confirm this?

Comment: If could add a description of the incident to the question, it would be better - since Youtube video are prone to being taken down.

Comment: [Please do not use codeblocks for emphasis or highlighting](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/3942/53718). It interferes with screen-readers, and is inappropriate usage, especially where *emphasis* or **strong emphasis/bold** should be used. In particular @jamauss should know better.

Comment: @Nij I'll stop using codeblocks for emphasis in comments when inline blockquotes are introduced. Until then, I'm going to follow [enderland's answer to that meta question](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/3943/29620), as there is no better tool. Italics and bold don't have the desired effect.

Comment: But there's no point to an inline blockquote. Either you want the quote separate, so use the > markup, or you want it inline but emphasised, so use the emph/stremph with * around "".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The offence committed by Marco Verratti is mentioned under [Law 12 - Fouls and Misconduct, Section 3: Disciplinary Action](http://theifab.com/#!/laws/fouls-and-misconduct/chapters/disciplinary-action).

> **Cautions for unsporting behaviour**
>
> There are different circumstances when a player must be cautioned for
>   unsporting behaviour including if a player:
>
> ...
>
> - uses a deliberate trick to pass the ball (including from a free kick) to the goalkeeper with the head, chest, knee etc. to circumvent the Law, whether or not the goalkeeper touches the ball with the hands.

Going down under no pressure to head the ball to the keeper certainly fits the act that this rule aims to punish and although the referee has drawn flak for brandishing the yellow card, he has followed the rule and taken appropriate action for Verratti's offence.